# Replace all values in given axis with minimum of given axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, aggregate

Im trying to implement this [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhxXr.png)   in python.
I end up with this piece of code:

```
def unknown(a, axis=0, p=0):
    if p >= 0 and p <=1:
        if not isinstance(a, np.ndarray):
            a = np.array(a, dtype=dtype)
        size = a.shape[axis]
        return (p/size)*(np.sum((a + (1 - p)), axis=axis, dtype=dtype))
    else:
        raise ValueError("parameter p should be in range 0,1")
```

Given code skips multiplication by min value in given axis. I have idea of creating new array identical to 'a' containing minimum values multiplied by (1-p) then add this matrix to 'a'. Sadly i dont know how to implement this so that i can specify axis. What is the most effective way to implement it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

to get the min value for a specified axis:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

# min value per row
np.min(a, axis=1)
```

Your formula could be:

```
(p/size)*np.sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype) + (1-p)*np.min(a, axis=axis)
```